# Save Word with Thumbnail

Tags: vbscript, scripting, ms-word

I want to see thumbnails from Word files in my explorer. Unfortunally i have to save every Word document with the "save with preview" option.(In the Word save dialog)

Now I want to write a little tool(VB6,VB.NET,C#,...) that uses a Word 2007 com object to automatically add thumbnails. Unfortunally i can't find a option to enable the Word preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Macro:**
It might be just as easy to write a VBA macro/script that does the same. The advantage is that you can record the opening, setting the options and saving, as a macro. That will give you the basic code to start with, and VBA will probably be easy for you as you already know VB6 and VB.NET.

It might even help you find the option in the COM application if it is available at all.

**VSTO:** I don't know in what version the preview option was introduced, but as far as I know, the development of the COM interface is somewhat behind of the .NET addin interface. So, if you can't find the option at all in the interface, you'd probably need VSTO (Visual Studion Tools for Office) to develop an addin that can control Word from the inside using the .NET interface that Word provides.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a com option. I tried to record a macro but the option is not set.

Comment: I was afraid so. I hope then that the option is available in VSTO. If not, it will be hard to do this automatically, unless you're using sendkeys or so to simulate a manual action (which should really be the very last resort).